# PHP PDO MYSQL receiving General error 2014 when there are several reasons error should not fire

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In the following code, a brand new connection is initiated with a mySql database via PDO, and the first activity is to lock tables.  However, that statement receives the general error 2014:

> Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute

No query has been executed, buffered or otherwise, and to add insult to injury, the MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY value is in fact already set.

Any ideas why I would receive this error on a fully-up-to-date php 7.4.3 Ubuntu 20.04 system?

Here's the code and the result:

```php
require_once("test-credentials.php") ;

$user = $_GLOBALS['user'] ;
$password = $_GLOBALS['password'] ;
$server = $_GLOBALS['hostname'] ;
$dbName = $_GLOBALS['dbname'] ;

$dsn = "mysql:host=$server;dbname=$dbName" ;
$options = [ PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false // no emulation mode for "real" prepared stmts
          ,  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION // Errors cause exception
          ,  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC // Default fetch mode
          ,  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS   => true
          ,  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true
            ] ;
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options) ;

$pdo->beginTransaction() ;
$pdo->query("LOCK TABLES ftsImageCtl WRITE") ;
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO ftsImageCtl (image1) VALUES(null)") ;
$imgDbId = $pdo->lastInsertId() ;
$pdo->query("UNLOCK TABLES") ;
$pdo->commit() ;
```

> php test.php
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. in /www/htdocs/GetChats/test.php:20
> Stack trace:
> #0 /www/htdocs/GetChats/test.php(20): PDO->query()
> #1 {main}
> thrown in /www/htdocs/GetChats/test.php on line 20

Video that demonstrates the problem: https://youtu.be/VKQd2--2fyQ

The instances where I've seen this discussed on Stack Overflow (and elsewhere) all seem to point to a query for which some rows remain unfetched.  That is clearly not the case here.

Comment: What's the point in beginning a transaction **and** trying to lock tables?

Comment: Which query is getting that error?

Comment: How are we supposed to use those credentials? We don't have access to your database server.

Comment: "However, that statement receives the general error 2014". [Nope, it doesn't](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/906d6112e707f50b3950dd28e0f0b42a/)

Comment: Actually, @Barmar you aren't supposed to access my database - that's the point of the external file test-credentials.php.  I believe that this issue is not associated with MY database, but rather with pdo and/or php and//or mysql.  Answer to hyour query is: LIne 20: the LOCK TABLES query.  I'll post a video.

Comment: @Phil: there are many reasons to lock a table.  In this case, the table (in the actual program) should remain locked across transactions.  There is synchronization done with a remote system that has no knowledge of our commit status.

Comment: @YourCommonSense ummm... yes, it does.  https://youtu.be/VKQd2--2fyQ.

Comment: Looks like this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70066 from https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php so you have to upgrade PHP

Comment: I think @Phil means [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html): "*LOCK TABLES is not transaction-safe **and implicitly commits any active transaction** before attempting to lock the tables*" thus effectively making a transaction statement useless

Comment: @Dennis I couldn't understand why you posted any credentials in the question. If we're going to test the code on our server, we'd use our own credentials.

Comment: @Barmar, I didn't.  those are mockups for anyone who might not understand. (Not you, certainly.)  However, those who watch the video closely will be able to scrape the values I used in that test.  they've been invalidated, of course